# A JavaScript that clicks automatically over a flash object on document ready?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, flash

I got a flash document I CAN'T modify, that starts its animations only when pressing a button it has on it. I tried EVERY script I found on the internet but nothing worked. I need to simulate the click on that button so the flash animation can start! Is this possible?

Comment: It may be possible to communicate with the flash object using Javascript in your page, but that would totally depend upon how the flash object is written and whether it allows that.  As far as I know, there is no generic way to click buttons in a flash object using Javascript that is running outside the Flash object.

Answer (score 1):

**If there are no APIs** (which give you access to the elements),
you cannot interact with the Flash UI, because the Flash content has its own context, where JavaScript has no access to it.

Comment: Flash objects can expose APIs via javascript, so with cooperation from the Flash object, it is possible to tell it to do things from Javascript, so it's a bit over reaching to say you cannot interact with a Flash object from Javascript.

Comment: Generally yes, but based on the question I guessed there are no APIs.

Comment: Your answer sounded absolute.  I'd suggest you qualify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decompile your flash file and get FLA-project of it. There it is possible to make required changes and create new swf.
There are many swf decompilers, but there is no 100% guarantee for successful decompilation (especially for big and complicated flash applications)